# Is there a way to reinstall a built in application in my Android phone?

Tags: system-apps

I accidentally  (unknowingly )  disabled  built in apps, I recently realized that I really need a few of them back. How do I reinstall them or bring them back?

Comment: If you really just DISABLED the apps, you can go to the Settings> Application Manager> All, and find them alphabetically to re-enable them. Just bring up the setting screen for the needed ones, and turn them back on. If you REMOVED the apps some way (which generally required ROOT), some re-installation is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can find disabled apps in Settings, Then App Manager(might be named something similar, per your device) Then you should be able to swipe left and right to find Downloaded apps, Apps on SD Card, All Apps, Then there should be one for disabled apps. Select the app and it will bring up the menu you used to disable them. Then you can re-enable them.